# Where does a postmessage from a worker called from the render process go?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, web-worker, postmessage

I am using ElectronJS to make an application that generates an STL file from an image and I am using OpenCV to access the values of each pixel of the image. A Worker is used to write the STL file. The complication that I am having is that I am not receiving the message in either the file that the worker is created (the same place that sends a message to the worker) or the main process.

The following is the creation of the worker:

```
let worker = new Worker('../workers/convertor.js')
```

This is the code for the worker

```
onmessage = function (e) {
   //Creating the write stream
   let stream = fs.createWriteStream(e.data[1].split('.')[0] + '.stl', {flags: 'w'})
   this.self.postMessage([50])

   convert(stream, e.data[2])
   self.close()
}
```

And this is how I send messages to the worker:

```
 function convertFile() {
    // Not converting if there is no file selected
    if(filePath != null) {
        // The mat for image analysis
        let src = cv.imread('img-for-analysis', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        // Variable to hold the pixel values of the image
        let pixelValues = [...Array(src.rows)].map(e => Array(src.cols).fill(null))
        //Storing the values of the pixels in the array
        for(let i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < src.cols; j++) {
                pixelValues[i][j] = src.ucharAt(i, j * src.channels())
            }
        }
        worker.postMessage([filePath, fileName, pixelValues])
    }
}
```

I've placed this piece of code in both my main.js and the js file where the worker is created in/sent messages from:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

All other parts of the code are functional, but I am not receiving any response in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Calling this.self.postmessage() is posting a message to the worker. I need to simply call postmessage() from the worker. In the file that I want to receive the message, I would do:

```
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    // Code
}
```